# How can I stop sending my hostname via DHCP?

Tags: networking, dhcp

Ubuntu sends my computer's configured hostname to any DHCP server it tries to use. How do I stop it from sending a hostname?

Comment: What is the version of your dhcp client? If `dhcp3` see the config in ` /etc/dhcp3`. It has a setting like this `send host-name "<hostname>";`

Comment: @Rinzwind, I'm using whatever the standard Ubuntu client is. It appears that there's an `/sbin/dhclient` which is probably it with a version `isc-dhclient-4.2.4`. While there's no `/etc/dhcp3`, there is an `etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` with a comment `Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's dhcp3-client package.` and with the line `send host-name = gethostname();`. Would commenting out that line stop it or do I have to change it to something to avoid it doing something like sending a default hostname if there's nothing configured?

Comment: I would assume yes :D (sorry, can not test it because I only have access to production servers at the moment ;) ).

Answer (score 3):

you can do it.

```
send host-name = gethostname();
```

This statement actually getting the host name of the system from the return value of function.

you can set it manually to some other name if you want.

```
send host-name =olathe ;
```

to send no host name: `send host-name = ;`

Comment: Is there a way to get it to send no host name rather than a custom one?

Comment: @Olathe edited last ,: 0

Comment: This does not seem to work in ubuntu 12.10. I tried to set "send host-name = ;" in "etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" but my hostname is still sent.