# Blank/empty hostname

Tags: dhcp, hostname

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and i was wondering if there is way to not send my hostname when connecting to a router? For example when I connect to my router I can see my laptop hostname when I log on the router, under "DHCP Leases".

I dont want to change my hostname, I would just like to not send anything so that under "Hostname" in my router my laptop mac address appears with no name. Is that possible? I have noticed sometimes that blank hostnames do appear for some connected devices.

Edit: I am aware of this [How can I stop sending my hostname via DHCP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365028/how-can-i-stop-sending-my-hostname-via-dhcp) however it does not seem to work under ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to tell us if you are running Ubuntu, and what version.

On my **Ubuntu 13.10**, I'd have to edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and comment the following line:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
```

"Commenting" a line is just putting an `#` before it, so it would look like this:

```
#send host-name = gethostname();
```

---

Edited: by the way, this was already asked:

[How can I stop sending my hostname via DHCP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365028/how-can-i-stop-sending-my-hostname-via-dhcp)

Comment: Sorry I am using ubuntu 12.10. I tried the above and unfortunately it does not work. I tried to even change my mac address but my hostname still appears in the router.